# Using the Pusher.com API for client to client events

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pusher

I have setup an account and app in the pusher.com API dashboard and have experimented with both private and public channels and client->client events - I have no trouble doing this.

My project is using CodeIgniter (latest) PHP framework (+ jQuery latest + pusher latest) and I have access to edit everything - nothing is out of bounds in terms of solutions, this is a non commercial project.

My aim is to have client/socket A send an event/message to client/socket B within 'channelX'.

I would like many people/sockets to be possible within 'channelX' - so for example we could have 10 clients connected to this channel, but within it I would like 2 parties to be able to communicate directly with each other (can be via server or just via pusher api).

At the moment, and where my understanding and research leads me: is that any event triggered in my 'channelX' private channel is sent to all clients - now I have used the 'exclude socket' parameter to make sure the event doesn't trigger on 'socketA' (the person doing the initiating of the event) - and this works when there is only 2 clients/sockets connected to a channel - but add more parties and it gets messy.

The question:
Should a channel ONLY have 2 clients/sockets if the events are only to be shared between two?

Ideally what I would like to do:
Have one master channel which holds all users - then each user should be able to send a 'ping' or 'poke' to one of the other users - without all of the other clients receiving this pusher event/trigger.

I do have code but my question is really theory based and so I'm not expecting bundles of code to come from this question - but the docs on the pusher.com website kind of miss this point (or perhaps I did!)

Thanks for any input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an old FAQ article on [how to implement 1-to-1 chat](http://pusher.tenderapp.com/kb/faq-common-requests/how-to-implement-1-to-1-chat) that may provide a strategy that suits your needs.

Comment: Thanks @leggetter I had come to a similar conclusion, I will have the server produce a private channel name and send that to the client via ajax for the client to be dynamically bound to the new private channel and then perhaps boot the user from the old channel / unbind to prevent any cross over